# Configure Multiple DataSource in Spring Boot with JNDI

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-data, jndi

I want to manage **multiple** DataSource using your Application Servers built-in features and access it using JNDI. I am using Spring boot with Spring JPA data.

I am able to configure the application.properties for single datasource:

```
spring.datasource.jndi-name=jdbc/customers
```

And my configuration in context.xml file as below:

```
<Resource name="jdbc/customer" auth="Container" type="javax.sql.DataSource"
               maxTotal="100" maxIdle="30" maxWaitMillis="10000"
               username="root" password="root" driverClassName="com.mysql.jdbc.Driver"
               url="jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/customer"/>
```

Everything works fine.

But when I am unable to configure for two datasource.

I am sure on the configuration in context.xml file:

```
 <Resource name="jdbc/customer" auth="Container" type="javax.sql.DataSource"
                   maxTotal="100" maxIdle="30" maxWaitMillis="10000"
                   username="root" password="root" driverClassName="com.mysql.jdbc.Driver"
                   url="jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/customer"/>

 <Resource name="jdbc/employee" auth="Container" type="javax.sql.DataSource"
                   maxTotal="100" maxIdle="30" maxWaitMillis="10000"
                   username="root" password="root" driverClassName="com.mysql.jdbc.Driver"
                   url="jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/employee"/>
```

**I am in doubt about the application.properties file configuration.**

I tried the below options with no success:

```
spring.datasource.jndi-name=jdbc/customers,jdbc/employee
```

Please  let me know any details on Spring boot with JNDI for multiple data source. I was looking for this configuration for days now.

Second Trial As per [Spring Boot Documentation](http://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/1.2.3.BUILD-SNAPSHOT/reference/htmlsingle/#howto-two-datasources)

```
spring.datasource.primary.jndi-name=jdbc/customer
spring.datasource.secondary.jndi-name=jdbc/project
```

Configuration class.

```
@Bean
@Primary
@ConfigurationProperties(prefix="datasource.primary")
public DataSource primaryDataSource() {
    return DataSourceBuilder.create().build();
}

@Bean
@ConfigurationProperties(prefix="datasource.secondary")
public DataSource secondaryDataSource() {
    return DataSourceBuilder.create().build();
}
```

The application does not get started. Though the tomcat server is getting started. No errors are printed in the log.

**Third Trial: With JndiObjectFactoryBean**

I have the below application.properties

```
spring.datasource.primary.expected-type=javax.sql.DataSource
spring.datasource.primary.jndi-name=jdbc/customer
spring.datasource.primary.jpa.database-platform=org.hibernate.dialect.MySQL5Dialect
spring.datasource.primary.jpa.show-sql=false
spring.datasource.primary.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto=validate

spring.datasource.secondary.jndi-name=jdbc/employee
spring.datasource.secondary.expected-type=javax.sql.DataSource
spring.datasource.secondary.jpa.database-platform=org.hibernate.dialect.MySQL5Dialect
spring.datasource.secondary.jpa.show-sql=false
spring.datasource.secondary.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto=validate
```

And the below java configuration:

```
@Bean(destroyMethod="")
@Primary
@ConfigurationProperties(prefix="spring.datasource.primary")
public FactoryBean primaryDataSource() {
    return new JndiObjectFactoryBean();
}

@Bean(destroyMethod="")
@ConfigurationProperties(prefix="spring.datasource.secondary")
public FactoryBean secondaryDataSource() {
    return new JndiObjectFactoryBean();
}
```

But still getting error:

```
Related cause: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'primaryDataSource' defined in class path resource [com/web/initializer/MvcConfig.class]: Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is javax.naming.NameNotFoundException: Name [jdbc/customer] is not bound in this Context. Unable to find [jdbc].
Related cause: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'secondaryDataSource' defined in class path resource [com/web/initializer/MvcConfig.class]: Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is javax.naming.NameNotFoundException: Name [jdbc/employee] is not bound in this Context. Unable to find [jdbc].
        at org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.onRefresh(EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.java:133)
        at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:474)
        at org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.refresh(EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.java:118)
        at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:686)
        at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:320)
        at org.springframework.boot.context.web.SpringBootServletInitializer.run(SpringBootServletInitializer.java:117)
        at org.springframework.boot.context.web.SpringBootServletInitializer.createRootApplicationContext(SpringBootServletInitializer.java:108)
        at org.springframework.boot.context.web.SpringBootServletInitializer.onStartup(SpringBootServletInitializer.java:68)
        at org.springframework.web.SpringServletContainerInitializer.onStartup(SpringServletContainerInitializer.java:175)
```

**Update:**
Trial using the below properties file:

```
  spring.datasource.primary.expected-type=javax.sql.DataSource
   spring.datasource.primary.jndi-name=java:comp/env/jdbc/customer

   spring.datasource.secondary.jndi-name=java:comp/env/jdbc/employee
   spring.datasource.secondary.expected-type=javax.sql.DataSource

   spring.jpa.database-platform=org.hibernate.dialect.MySQL5Dialect
   spring.jpa.show-sql=false
   spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto=validate
```

It creates all the tables in customer schema, but fails trying to find the other tables also.(from the second schema)

Comment: `DataSourceBuilder` isn't for use with JNDI. If you have multiple datasource from JNDI, you have to retrieve them yourself.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

This is the solution for your third trial a little bit modified.
Consider this solution (Spring Boot 1.3.2):

application.properties file:

```
spring.datasource.primary.jndi-name=java:/comp/env/jdbc/SecurityDS
spring.datasource.primary.driver-class-name=org.postgresql.Driver

spring.datasource.secondary.jndi-name=java:/comp/env/jdbc/TmsDS
spring.datasource.secondary.driver-class-name=org.postgresql.Driver

spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.dialect=org.hibernate.dialect.PostgreSQL9Dialect
spring.jpa.show-sql=false
```

Configuration:

```
@Configuration@ EnableConfigurationProperties
public class AppConfig {

    @Bean@ ConfigurationProperties(prefix = "spring.datasource.primary")
    public JndiPropertyHolder primary() {
        return new JndiPropertyHolder();
    }

    @Bean@ Primary
    public DataSource primaryDataSource() {
        JndiDataSourceLookup dataSourceLookup = new JndiDataSourceLookup();
        DataSource dataSource = dataSourceLookup.getDataSource(primary().getJndiName());
        return dataSource;
    }

    @Bean@ ConfigurationProperties(prefix = "spring.datasource.secondary")
    public JndiPropertyHolder secondary() {
        return new JndiPropertyHolder();
    }

    @Bean
    public DataSource secondaryDataSource() {
        JndiDataSourceLookup dataSourceLookup = new JndiDataSourceLookup();
        DataSource dataSource = dataSourceLookup.getDataSource(secondary().getJndiName());
        return dataSource;
    }

    private static class JndiPropertyHolder {
        private String jndiName;

        public String getJndiName() {
            return jndiName;
        }

        public void setJndiName(String jndiName) {
            this.jndiName = jndiName;
        }
    }
}
```

And then you can follow guide http://docs.spring.io/spring-data/jpa/docs/1.3.0.RELEASE/reference/html/jpa.repositories.html to use your datasources with jpa repositories.

Answer (score 6):

You could use a plain `JndiObjectFactoryBean` for this. Simply replace the `DataSourceBuilder` with a `JndiObjectFactoryBean` should do the trick.

Java configuration

```
@Bean(destroyMethod="")
@Primary
@ConfigurationProperties(prefix="datasource.primary")
public FactoryBean primaryDataSource() {
    return new JndiObjectFactoryBean();
}

@Bean(destroyMethod="")
@ConfigurationProperties(prefix="datasource.secondary")
public FactoryBean secondaryDataSource() {
    return new JndiObjectFactoryBean();
}
```

Properties

```
datasource.primary.jndi-name=jdbc/customer
datasource.primary.expected-type=javax.sql.DataSource
datasource.secondary.jndi-name=jdbc/project
datasource.secondary.expected-type=javax.sql.DataSource
```

You can set every property of the [`JndiObjectFactoryBean`](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/jndi/JndiObjectFactoryBean.html) using the `@ConfigurationProperties` annotation. (See the `expected-type` I added, but you could also set `cache` or `lookup-on-startup` etc.).

**Note:** when doing a JNDI lookup set the `destroyMethod` to an `""` else you might get the situation that when the application is shutdown your JNDI resource is getting closed/shutdown as well. This is not something you want in a shared environment.

Comment: Still no luck. A have added the option to the original question.

Comment: Have you read the error message? Either set the `resource-ref` property to `true`  (`datasource.primary.resource-ref=true` or prefix the name with `java:comp/env/`...

Comment: Tried both the options(resource-ref property to true and java:comp/env/ ). It creates the table for the primary schema and throws an error "unable to find table " for the tables in secondary schema.I think the second datasource is not getting picked automatically by spring boot?

Comment: Yes it is but initializing works only for the `@Primary` one.

Comment: Is there a way to use both the datasource.

Comment: That is a different question. This was about multiple databases from JNDI. Using it with JPA and how to initialize are different questions.

Comment: Yes .in understand that. Was trying to use the two datasouce configured through JNDI, using Spring data JPA.i was able to use single datasource successfully. Any help is much appreciated.!!

Comment: And please select this answer (or another) to mark this one answered.

Comment: I have raised a separate question on that http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33767993/multiple-databases-jndi-with-spring-data-jpa-to-initialize.If any body is aware of the reason for the error please help

Answer (score 6):

It works for me and contains less code

```
@Configuration
public class Config {
    @Value("${spring.datasource.primary.jndi-name}")
    private String primaryJndiName;

    @Value("${spring.datasource.secondary.jndi-name}")
    private String secondaryJndiName;

    private JndiDataSourceLookup lookup = new JndiDataSourceLookup();

    @Primary
    @Bean(destroyMethod = "") // destroy method is disabled for Weblogic update app ability
    public DataSource primaryDs() {
        return lookup.getDataSource(primaryJndiName);
    }

    @Bean(destroyMethod = "") // destroy method is disabled for Weblogic update app ability
    public DataSource secondaryDs() {
        return lookup.getDataSource(secondaryJndiName);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

In my case, when i start my application using Spring Boot App, the database configurations are read on application-dev.properties, when I publish on tomcat, using datasources, was necessary add a validation to check if my profile is prod, in this case, i do a jndi lookup

```
@Bean(name = "dsName")
@ConfigurationProperties("ds.datasource.configuration")
public DataSource dataSource(@Qualifier("dsProperties") DataSourceProperties db1DataSourceProperties)
{

    if(Arrays.asList(environment.getActiveProfiles()).contains("prod"))
    {
        final JndiDataSourceLookup dataSourceLookup = new JndiDataSourceLookup();
        return dataSourceLookup.getDataSource("java:comp/env/jdbc/DS1");
    }
    else
    {
        return db1DataSourceProperties.initializeDataSourceBuilder().type(HikariDataSource.class).build();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The concise way I get success and explore more

1. set up many jndi resources in external tomcat , that you can start/stop in eclipse.Note- double click the tomcat in eclipse and select use workspace metedata , means dont deploy the app to tomcat webapp folder. Add jndi resources in respective eclipse server files( context.xml - ResourceLink, server.xml - Resource , web.xml - resource-ref).
2. no need to set spring.datasource.* in application.properties. since jndi-contest which is a datasource type( i.e. `type="javax.sql.DataSource"`) is exported to external server.
3. in SpringBootApplication annotated class , create the datasource beans from all the jndi resources(those setup as per #1) through jndi lookup

   ```
   @Bean(name = "abcDataSource")

   public DataSource getAbcDataSource() {

       JndiDataSourceLookup dataSourceLookup = new JndiDataSourceLookup();
       DataSource dataSource = dataSourceLookup.getDataSource("java:comp/env/jdbc/abcDataSource");
       return dataSource; 
   }
   ```
4. if spring jdbc used in your project then provide the above datasource to create a jdbcTemplate bean

   ```
   @Bean(name = "jdbcAbcTemplate")

   public JdbcTemplate abcJdbcTemplate(@Lazy @Qualifier("abcDataSource")

   DataSource refDS) 
   {        
     return new JdbcTemplate(refDS);
   }
   ```
5. just autowire a property of DataSource type and get systemout its details to explore more.

Answer (score 0):

While the above answers are good I am going to add one more to illustrate a deadly gotcha if mixing jndi and full data connection configuration. In a typical development environment you may fully qualify the database connection in your local dev environment then use jndi as you push to qa, etc.. Your
application .properties looks like so:

```
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:sqlserver://server.domain.org:1433;databaseName=dbxx
spring.datasource.username=userxxyyzz
spring.datasource.password=passxxyyzz
spring.datasource.platform=mssql
spring.datasource.driverClassName=com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver
```

and application-qa.properties like so:

```
spring.datasource.jndi-name=java:jboss/datasources/dbxx
```

The problem arises when you have to define your own beans to have multiple datasources. If you use the default Spring managed datasource then it automatically detects jndi vs fully qualified connection and returns  a datasource with no change needed in the application code. If you define your own datasource it no longer does this. If you have application.properties like so:

```
spring.custom.datasource.url=jdbc:sqlserver://server.domain.org:1433;databaseName=dbxx
    spring.custom.datasource.username=userxxyyzz
    spring.custom.datasource.password=passxxyyzz
    spring.custom.datasource.platform=mssql
    spring.custom.datasource.driverClassName=com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver
```

and application-qa.properties like so:

```
spring.custom.datasource.jndi-name=java:jboss/datasources/dbxx
```

with a datasource bean like so, as suggested in Spring docs https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/2.1.11.RELEASE/reference/html/howto-data-access.html

```
  @Primary
  @Bean(name="customDataSourcePropertiesBean")
  @ConfigurationProperties("spring.custom.datasource")
  public DataSourceProperties customDataSourceProperties() {
      return new DataSourceProperties();
  }

  @Primary
  @Bean(name="customDataSourceBean")
  @ConfigurationProperties("spring.custom.datasource") 
  public HiakriDataSource customDataSource(@Qualifier("customDataSourcePropertiesBean") DataSourceProperties properties) {
    return properties.initializeDataSourceBuilder().type(HikariDataSource.class).build();
  }
```

This datasource builder does not attempt to read the jndi config in application-qa.properties and silently fails back to application.properties returning the WRONG database connection. Resolution is fairly simple - test which environment you are in and customize the type of database connection created. Debugging this was a bear, as the symptom was that the app appeared to be ignoring application-qa.properties. I share to spare others the pain. Add spring.profiles.active=qa etc. to your properties files to know which environment you are in then:

```
  @Value("${spring.profiles.active}")
  String profile;

  @Value("${spring.custom.jndi-name}")
  String jndi;

  @Primary
  @Bean(name="customDataSourcePropertiesBean")
  @ConfigurationProperties("spring.custom.datasource")
  public DataSourceProperties customDataSourceProperties() {
      return new DataSourceProperties();
  }

  @Primary
  @Bean(name="customDataSourceBean")
  @ConfigurationProperties("spring.custom.datasource") 
  public DataSource customDataSource(@Qualifier("customDataSourcePropertiesBean") DataSourceProperties properties) {
    if(profile.equals("localhost")) {
        return DataSourceBuilder
            .create()
                .username(properties.getDataUsername())
                .password(properties.getPassword())
                .url(properties.getUrl())
                .driverClassName(properties.getDriverClassName())
                .build();
    }else {
        JndiDataSourceLookup dataSourceLookup = new JndiDataSourceLookup();
        return dataSourceLookup.getDataSource(jndi);
    }
  }
```